# Get ssl certificates thumbprint from directory in powershell

Tags: powershell, ssl

I have an application that is throwing an exception because the ssl certificate is not installed on my machine. I know the tumbprint of the missing certificate but I do not know how to find it by name.

I have done this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

And verified that the cert i need is not installed. I have the certs in my source code directory(c:\source\project\certs) but I need to know which cert in the directory to install.

Is there a way to list the certs like in the line above but from the  "c:\source\project\certs" folder instead of the cert store?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$password= ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Pass" -AsPlainText -Force

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\source\project\certs" -Filter *.pfx | % {
    $certobject = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
    $certobject.import($_.FullName, $password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::DefaultKeySet)
    $certobject.Thumbprint
}
```

Comment: @PeterSchneider no it wont import them into the cert store, just into the object